# JFrame freezes after clicking a button

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame that has a JTextField and a JButton. I am trying to get the count of elements from a user's input in the JTextField. However, after pressing the button, the JFrame freezes. Here is my code:

```
    private void bubbleSortButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
        // read the user's input from text field and store it in to the elements string
        String elements = inputField.getText();

        // initialize a scanner for the elements
        Scanner input = new Scanner(elements);

        // initialize a counter variable for counting the number of elements input by the user
        int n = 0;

        // increment the counter variable as long as it could read a next token
        while (input.hasNext())
            n++;
   }
```

I've already tried to search for solutions, but nothing answered my problem. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Why are you using a Scanner with the text from the text field. If you want to know the number of characters in the String just use the `String.length()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
while (input.hasNext()) 
  n++;
```

..to something like..

```
while (input.hasNext()) { 
  input.getNext(); 
  n++; 
}
```

Otherwise the conditional will be true forever.

Sourced via comment.